# Play Framework Internet Explorer parser error

Tags: internet-explorer, playframework, html-parsing

> For request 'POST /' [Error parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded]

I only get this error on IE. All the other browsers handles it without being crybabies. Tried to Google this error, but could not find anything helpful. Any idea what should be done to avoid it? Maybe I might be doing something wrong in general use of framework that I don't know of?

Comment: Could you add a bit more details like code samples and full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing on IE9 right now on Play 2.1!

Comment: Same here with Play 2.0.4 and IE9. No log statements from play, no exception.

Comment: Same as GarfieldKlon, only on IE10.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same with IE10, and I traced it to the POST content being:

```
 email=fred@example.com&password=asd&=
```

The final "&=" causes an exception in FormUrlEncodedParser, which is swallowed and converted to a BadRequest in BodyParsers.tolerantFormUrlEncoded.

In summary, to my understanding, this is the combination of two bugs:

- MSIE10 is sending those two characters for whatever reason (there seem to be several possible such reasons).
- Play does not tolerate those useless characters in the query string (where it is customary that unknown parameters in URLs should be ignored by server apps). I've reported this as a bug: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/1185

In my case, the "whatever reason" was a  tag with no "name" attribute. In GafrieldKlon's case, it was an unclosed <input type="hidden". Your's may be another.

Comment: Any quick fix for that?

Comment: In my case, the submit button had no name on it. Adding a name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps someone else, I just ran into this issue and after debugging I found out that a javascript validation library was introducing a hidden input that IE subsequently encoded.

The library came from here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

I happen to be using play 2.2.2 so it looks like when 2.3.0 is out this shouldn't be an issue.

My fix was to edit the validation script and comment out the addition of a hidden input. In my use-case that bit of code was not necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've debugged the Play! sources and I've found the code that is responsible for this error. It's the method *def tolerantFormUrlEncoded* in *ContentTypes.scala* 
There is thrown a NoSuchElementException, and this was caused by a non-closing `<input type="hidden"`

So I recommend that you check your form.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate this behavior in a controlled environment (with a plain form and a PHP server). It happened in IE but not Chrome (didn't test Firefox or Safari). The problem is only partly Play's handling of form data.

What caused it was this: IE seems to bundle up every form field with a name attribute (empty or not) and put it into the post data. This means that any form element with an empty name attribute (`name=""`) will be represented. This is based on the idea of "successful controls" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). The spec is unclear (from what I could find) on whether having a "control name" means just having a name attribute present or having a name attribute with a non-empty value. It seems that IE takes this literally and collects everything while the others do a nice extra step and filter out the controls with empty names.

Given a the following sample form:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <label>
        Name
        <input name="name"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Email
        <input name="email"/>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" name="">Send 1</button>
</form>
```

IE9 resulted in appending `&=Send` to the POST data. In IE10/11, it resulted in the aforementioned `&=` at the end. For the record, `<button>` is supposed to submit the explicit `value` attribute and not the tag contents.

However, in our case (I'm a co-worker of kflorence's and I took a look at this in our codebase to give it a fresh set of eyes), our HTML was clean when it hit the browser. What slohr said (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529360/2684520) is what was plaguing us.

So, check your form HTML for any empty `name` attributes. If that's clean, you might have some JS injecting an offending field or modifying a field either on submit for the form or on click for the button. If your form HTML is clean, this bug shouldn't affect you.